# How to combine multiple rows into single row with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I need help on how to insert the data into temporary table with multiple conditions. I have 3 tables with linking with each other and my problem is the value of the Amount in **AmountIntakeVendorRequisition** return in single row for each Amount. So I need to combine each Amount with same 'AmountIntakeVendorId' into Quaters columns (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) in temporary table. Below are the tables for my case. Thanks in advance!

**AmountIntake**

```
 ------ ---------------------- --------------- ------------- 
| id   |  AmountIntakeBucketId|     CenterId  |   ProjectId |   
 ------ ---------------------- --------------- ------------- 
|  400 |                 94   |         C1000 |       P100  | 
|  401 |                 95   |         C1001 |       P101  | 
|  402 |                 96   |         C1002 |       P102  | 
|  403 |                 97   |         C1003 |       P103  | 
 ------ ---------------------- --------------- -------------
```

**AmountIntakeVendor**

```
 ------ ----------------- --------------- --------------
| id   |  AmountIntakeId |     VendorId  |   ProjectName| 
 ------ ----------------- --------------- --------------
|  411 |             400 |             1 |    Microsoft | 
|  412 |             400 |             2 |         Dell | 
|  413 |             400 |             4 |       Google | 
|  414 |             400 |             4 |       Huawei | 
 ------ ----------------- ---------------- -------------
```

**AmountIntakeVendorRequisition**

```
  ------ ----------------------  ---------------------------- -------------------------- ------------
| id   |  AmountIntakeVendorId|                    StartDt |                    EndDt |    Amount   |
 ------ ---------------------- ---------------------------- -------------------------- -------------
| 1771 |                  411 |    2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 |  2019-06-30 23:59:59.000 |     1000.00 |
| 1772 |                  411 |    2019-07-01 00:00:00.000 |  2019-09-31 23:59:59.000 |     1430.00 |
| 1773 |                  411 |    2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 |  2019-12-31 23:59:59.000 |     2000.00 |
| 1774 |                  412 |    2019-07-01 00:00:00.000 |  2019-09-31 23:59:59.000 |     5000.00 |
 ------  ---------------------- --------------------------- -------------------------- -------------
```

**Expected Result**

```
 ----------- ----------------------  ------------ -------------- ------------- ------------- 
| ProjectId |          ProjectName |          Q1 |           Q2 |          Q3 |          Q4 |        
 ----------- ---------------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ------------- 
|      P100 |            Microsoft |        NULL |      1000.00 |    1430.00  |     2000.00 |  
|      P101 |                 Dell |        NULL |      5000.00 |        NULL |        NULL |         
 ----------  ---------------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- -------------
```

I've created the table for inserting the data but I'm stuck at inserting the 'Amount' into the @tempTable for each Quaters (Q1,Q2,Q2,Q4)

```
  DECLARE @AIBId Int = 94
  DECLARE @tempTable TABLE            
 (            
  ProjectId INT,            
  ProjectName NVARCHAR(100),              
  Q1 DECIMAL (12,2), --1
  Q2 DECIMAL (12,2), -- 4
  Q3 DECIMAL (12,2), --7
  Q4 DECIMAL (12,2)  --10    
 )       

INSERT into @tempTable
SELECT *
AI.ProjectId,
AIV.ProjectName,
Month(AISR.StartDate) AS Quater,
CASE Quater
WHEN 1 THEN AISR.Amount
WHEN IS NULL THEN NULL
END AS Q1
CASE Quater
WHEN 4 THEN AISR.Amount
WHEN IS NULL THEN NULL
END AS Q2
CASE Quater
WHEN 7 THEN AISR.Amount
WHEN IS NULL THEN NULL
END AS Q3
CASE Quater
WHEN 10 THEN AISR.Amount
WHEN IS NULL THEN NULL
END AS Q4
END 
FROM AmountIntake AI
LEFT JOIN AmountIntakeVendor AIV on AI.Id = AIV.AmountIntakeId
LEFT JOIN AmountIntakeVendorRequisition AIVR on AIV.ID = AIVR.AmountIntakeVendorId
WHERE AI.AmountIntakeBucketId = @AIBId 

SELECT * from @tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` query seems good with just minor update as -

```
SELECT AI.ProjectId
      ,AIV.ProjectName
      ,Month(AISR.StartDate) AS Quater
      ,CASE Month(AISR.StartDate) WHEN 1 THEN AIVR.Amount END AS Q1
      ,CASE Month(AISR.StartDate) WHEN 4 THEN AIVR.Amount END AS Q2
      ,CASE Month(AISR.StartDate) WHEN 7 THEN AISR.Amount END AS Q3
      ,CASE Month(AISR.StartDate) WHEN 10 THEN AISR.Amount END AS Q4
FROM AmountIntake AI
LEFT JOIN AmountIntakeVendor AIV on AI.Id = AIV.AmountIntakeId
LEFT JOIN AmountIntakeVendorRequisition AIVR on AIV.ID = AIVR.AmountIntakeVendorId
WHERE AI.AmountIntakeBucketId = @AIBId
```

`CASE` statement automatically assigns NULL if it doesn't meet the criteria so no need to explicitly assign it.

Comment: Ive removed and excuted the query but still its showing the error at ```CASE Quater ``` 
```Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.```

Comment: Ahh,My Bad. Aliases doesn't work in select statement. Please try the edited version....